# IgA-s in an immune system vaccined intramuscularly against Hepatisis A

Tags: immunology, antibody, vaccination, immunoglobin, hepatitis

As IgA are immunoglobulins associated with secretion and mucosis membranes, I am interested whether after intramuscular vaccination with [Hepatitis A vaccine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_A_vaccine) IgA antibodies will be produced by the immune system **before** an actual infection?

Also, would they be secreted into breast milk, intestine lumen etc. **before** the infection coming in a traditional (gestational) way?

Or does it take to have the antigen presented at the mucosis mambrane to start IgA production or secretion?

Answer (score 1):

Antibodies are produced *after* exposure to cognate antigen.

Remember that B cells start off expressing membrane IgM and/or IgD. IgA requires class switching recombination at the B-cell receptor locus to the IgA isotype. Further differentiation of the B cells to antibody-secreting plasma cells results in soluble IgA production and immunologic memory to the antigen. Whether you'll get IgA, IgE or IgG antibodies against the vaccine will largely depend on the signals they get in the muscle, however (Figure 1). I think IgG is largely a result, since the tissue antiviral response is often interferon gamma (Figure 2).

The importance of intramuscular vaccination is outlined [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1118997/), just in case it wasn't apparent.

[image]

Figure 1. Activated helper T cells that can recognize the same antigen mediate the class switch by providing co-stimulatory signals and cytokines. [Source](https://step1.medbullets.com/immunology/105061/humoral-mediated-immunity)

[image]

Figure 2. Class-switching continued. Source: Parham, The Immune System, 4th Ed.

Comment: Then I see it is unlikely to have IgA produced after vaccination, am I right? As a side note - the linked paper seems to compare only muscle/fat injections, but no oral delivery.